# Raspberry journalctl ログについて

Tags: raspberry-pi

Raspberry PiのJournalctlでログを見ると、再起動後のログしか表示されません。

journald.confのStorageはpersistentに設定してログは`/var/log/jurnal`に変更してあります。
Raspbian-liteをインストールし、journald.conf以外は変更しておりません。
`journalctl --list-boot`で見てもID0の１つしか見えません。`journalctl -b -1`のコマンドはエラーとなります。

Raspbianのバージョンも最新のを含め２，３試したのですが同様です。
Raspberry Piの仕様なのでしょうか？初心者のため何か設定不足しているのかと思うのですが。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 念の為に確認しますが、`/var/log/journal` ディレクトリは作成済み、という事でよろしいですか？

Answer (score 1):

ログをRAM DISK上のファイルに書き込んではいませんか？

Raspberryの外部記憶(補助記憶装置)はSDカードです。
SDカードは書き込み回数に制限がある事から、RAMの一部をファイルのようにつかえるRAM DISKを作って、その上にログファイルを作ることが一般的です。（SDカードへの書き込み回数が限度を超えるとSDカードが壊れる(データの読み書きができなくなる)ので、書き込みの多いログファイルを書き込み回数制限のないRAMの上に作るのです）

RAM DISKは、読み書きが早くてですが、シャットダウンや、再起動したりすると内容が失われます。ログをRAM DISK上に作っているのであれば、再起動やシャットダウンでログの内容が失われます。
　Kaznnさんの現象は、これではないかと思われます。

＜対策＞
ログを残したいのであれば、シャットダウンや再起動の前にログファイルをSDカード上のファイルに書き込み、起動時にSDカード上のファイルからRAM DISK上のログファイルにデータをコピーするといった操作が必要です。

Answer (score 0):

早速のご享受ありがとうございます。
Fumu 7 さんのご指摘のようなRAM DISKは使用しておりません。
私の場合、syslog,messagesのログはリブートしても残っています。journalctlのログのみ表示できません。
普通Raspianをお使いの方は、再起動してもjournalのログは残っているのでしょうか？
色々試行錯誤しているのですが、解決出来ません、どのような情報での良いので何かヒントになるような事があれなお教え下さい。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 質問者の kaznn さんでしょうか？　もしアカウントが2つに分離してしまった場合、マージできますので [お問い合わせください](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)。質問者であれば、回答に対するリアクションをその回答へのコメントや質問本文への追記として投稿できます。コメント的なものを回答として投稿するといずれ削除されてしまうと思われますので、アカウントをマージすることをお勧めします。もしまだ kaznn さんとしてログインできる場合は、同じ内容を質問本文への追記などの形で再投稿してください。

Comment: 早速のご享受ありがとうございます。
Fumu 7 さんのご指摘のようなRAM DISKは使用しておりません。
 私の場合、syslog,messagesのログはリブートしても残っています。journalctlのログのみ表示できません。
 普通Raspianをお使いの方は、再起動してもjournalのログは残っているのでしょうか？
 色々試行錯誤しているのですが、解決出来ません、どのような情報での良いので何かヒントになるような事があれなお教え下さい。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: すいません、私の言い方が悪かったですが、「コメントとして投稿」というのは、Fumu 7 さんの回答へのコメントという意味です。やはり、[アカウントのマージ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)をお勧めします。